# Using axios interceptor in Vue project

Tags: javascript, http-headers, axios

I have components that are making get requests in their created methods. I am using oidc client for authorization. I would like to set the each request header with the token that I get from oidc. I have made a `http.js` file in the root of the project, that looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import AuthService from "./AuthService";

const authService = new AuthService();
let token;

axios.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {
    await authService.getUser().then(res => {
        if (res) {
            token = res.id_token;
            config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
    });

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('interceptor', config);
    return config;
}, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

I am not sure if this is the way to set the interceptors and how to actually use them, because on each request I see that they are not being set and nothing is being logged in the console. How is this suppose to be set up?

Comment: the purpose of interceport to modify request response sync, not async for async add this in resolve.

Comment: .then(do something here).then(result cb)

Comment: here on reponse u get token, set that to `sessionStorage` and on request get it synchronously

Comment: I am mostly wondering how to use this on each request. Since it is not logging anything in the console, this function is obviously not being called. So, my question is mostly about how to actually use this in components on each api call

Comment: Your code seems correct. howvere it depends how you are creating instance. You should not create multiple instance of axios.